# nodejs sinon how to stub inline require object from a class

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, stub, stubbing

I am trying to stub a class which does some stuff at inline require line. For example here lets say I am writing a unit test for abc-handler.js which depends on `query-helper` and `logger`. On the other hand, `query-helper` also depends on `logger`. However, I couldn't find a proper way to deal with stubbing logger and injecting it into related dependencies.

Here is some sample classes I have.

**query-helper.js**

```
var logger = require('./log/logger.js').getDefaultLogger();

class QueryHelper {
  static save() {
    // save stuff
  }
}
```

**abc-handler.js**

```
const logger = require('./log/logger.js').getDefaultLogger();
const QueryHelper = require('./query-helper.js');
var Handler = require('./handler.js');

/**
    Handler for 'binance' exchange
*/
class ABCHandler extends Handler {
    constructor(params) {
        super(params);
    }

    doStuff() {}
}
```

**logger.js**

```
var Log = require('log');
var fs = require('fs');
var dir = './logs';
const config = require('./config.js');
class LoggerFactory {
    static getDefaultLogger() {
        this._createDir();
        if (this.logger === null || this.logger === undefined) {
            this.logger = new Logger("application");
        }
        return this.logger;
    }

    static _createDir() {
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        }
    }
}

class Logger {
    constructor(operationType) {
        this.logger = new Log("debug", fs.createWriteStream("logs/" + operationType + ".log"), {flags: "a"});
    }
}

module.exports = LoggerFactory;
```

Here is the example block from unit-test. Here abcHandler creates `./log` directory which shouldn't happen because I am passing loggerStub

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
var Log = require('log');
...

logger = proxyquire('./logger.js', {'./config.js': config});
loggerStub = sinon.createStubInstance(Log);
_createDirStub = sinon.stub(logger, "getDefaultLogger").returns(loggerStub);

queryHelper = proxyquire('./query-helper.js' , {'./logger.js': logger});
queryHelperGetLastDataStub = sinon.stub(queryHelper, "save");

abcHandler = proxyquire('.abc-handler.js'
                                    , {'./logger.js': logger,
                                        './query-helper.js': queryHelper,
                                        './config.js': config});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this initializing `proxyquire` with `noCallThru()`.

```
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noCallThru();
```

explained here https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire#preventing-call-thru-to-original-dependency